# Android: preview shows different styling - action bar

Tags: android, android-studio

Just started learning developing android in android studio, and created a custom theme which needs to hide the action bar on a inheriting styling.

On runtime the theme actually does hides the action bar but the preview does not, which makes it a bit difficult creating a layout based on the preview.

I've probably done something wrong or just not understanding how to use theme's and stylings with the preview correctly.

**The custom theme I've made**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  ...   
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.MainLayout">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

*The intention is to use the .MainLayout styling on certain activities instead of the whole application.*

**How I'am applying the usage in manifest file**

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MainLayout">
        ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

As explained this does hides the action bar on runtime but doe'snt in the preview.
[image]

I also tested how the preview does behave on applying the style directly in the layout.xml file.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
  ...
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MainLayout"
</RelativeLayout>
```

*For testing purpose I've added an extra styling in the **AppTheme.MainLayout***

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

**Result**

[image]

**What I am observing on this is:**

The preview doesn't hides the action bar but does apply other styling (like the text color) correctly.

To wrap this question up: why is the preview different on not hiding the action bar when using the .MainLayout, and how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Preview 'settings'
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your Design layout manager try to select Theme (click AppTheme).

[image: AppTheme]

Try to change:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: dieter_h thanks for your response, apparently the preview settings already using AppTheme like you suggested.

Comment: Than try to change it to AppTheme.NoActionBar

Comment: + 1 for helping me out here. By changing this parent class into .NoActionBar does hide the action bar in the preview. But I need to hide the action bar only on certain activities, and this won't allow an action bar on any other activity..